# Parse a RegEx pattern

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Is there any way to parse a Complex RegEx pattern(containing several `named groups` as well as several `numbered groups` and `non-capturing groups`) and report about each `groupname` or `groupnumber` along with pattern text.

Suppose, I do have a RegEx pattern like this:

```
  (?im)(?<x>\b[a-s03]+\b)(?-i)(?<a>\p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?<c>.+?;(?<d>.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))))
```

And I like to extract:=

```
  Named groups:
  x==>(?<x>\b[a-s03]+\b)
  a==>(?<a>\p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?<c>.+?;(?<d>.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))))
  b==>(?<b>.+?:(?<c>.+?;(?<d>.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30)))))
  c==>(?<c>.+?;(?<d>.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))
  d==>(?<d>.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30)))

  Numbered groups:
  1==>(\k'x'|sos30)

  Non-capturing-groups:
  1st==>(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))
```

**Purpose of this Requirement:**

I do have a large database of complex RegEx patterns. The previous programmar worked on this did not use any comment [`(?#...)`] while preparing these complex patterns, moreover no `linebreaks` exists within those patterns. I have to modify those patterns some cases and also have to use comment within those patterns. Now it is something like searching a needle in the haystakes. I simply could not use RegEx for this purpose. So, I inclined to use a parser for this case.

**What I tried:**

I tried `GetGroupNames` and `GetGroupNumbers` collection for that purpose. I could extract only the `Names/Numbers` of the `groups`, but not the corresponding textual patterns.

**I am looking for a Non-RegEx solution/some hints.**

Comment: I'm not aware of any pre existing solutions to parse regular expressions. Although it probably shouldn't be immensely difficult to make something like it yourself if you simply loop through the line, capture opening parenthesis and look for the corresponding closing parenthesis. Based on the textual pattern you could see what sort of group it is.

Comment: @Patrickdev: Thank you, for giving your time comment. Actually the example I described is a very simple one and there is no `parenthesis` at all, where as actual patterns are much more more complex(mostly with nested structures and lots of parenthesis with the escaped ones also). But, yes, I am agree with you for suggestion to prepare a new Parser. But, it would be something like re-inventing the wheel. Certainly I will think about it if no there's any other solution for that.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.regex101.com - it could be of help here.

Comment: @Lindrian: Thanks for your comment. But, I do require a `RegEx parser` through which I would be able to parse a very large numbers of Complex RegEx patterns. Personally I do use `Regexbuddy` for creating and editing regex patterns, which I believe the best tool one must have, very explanatory in this regard. But, I am not going to manual work for that. Moreover the site you mentioned is very much `pythonic`, I require a `.NET compatible regex engine` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this, for this:

```
(?im)(?<x>\b[a-s03]+\b)(?-i)(?<a>\p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?'c'.+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))))
```

This, as the Output:

```
(0)<0>:     (?im)(?<x>\b[a-s03]+\b)(?-i)(?<a>\p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?'c'.+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))))
(1)<x>:     \b[a-s03]+\b
(2)<a>:     \p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?'c'.+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))
(3)<b>:     .+?:(?'c'.+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30)))
(4)<c>:     .+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))
(5)<5>:     .+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30)
(6)<6>:     \k'x'|sos30
```

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Module Module1
Public DictGroups As New OrderedDictionary
Public DictTrackers As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
Public intGroups As Integer = 0
Public CommandGroup As Boolean = False
Sub Main()
    Dim regexToEval As String = "(?im)(?<x>\b[a-s03]+\b)(?-i)(?<a>\p{L}+?,(?<b>.+?:(?'c'.+?;(.+?(?:\d|sample-text|(\k'x'|sos30))))))"
    Dim curChar As String = ""
    DictGroups.Add(0, "(0)<0>: " & vbTab)
    DictTrackers.Add(0, True)
    For i = 1 To regexToEval.Length
        Dim iChar As String = regexToEval.Substring(i - 1, 1)
        If curChar <> "\" AndAlso iChar = ")" Then EndGroup()
        AddStrToTrackers(iChar)
        If curChar = "\" OrElse iChar <> "(" OrElse regexToEval.Length < i + 2 Then curChar = iChar : Continue For
        If regexToEval.Substring(i, 1) = "?" Then
            i += 1 : AddStrToTrackers("?")
            If regexToEval.Substring(i, 1) = ":" Then i += 1 : AddStrToTrackers(":") : curChar = ":" : Continue For
            Dim NameLength As Integer = 0
            If regexToEval.Substring(i, 1) = "<" Or regexToEval.Substring(i, 1) = "'" Then
                i += 1 : AddStrToTrackers(regexToEval.Substring(i - 1, 1))
                i += 1
                For x = i To regexToEval.Length
                    If regexToEval.Substring(x - 1, 1) = ">" Or regexToEval.Substring(x - 1, 1) = "'" Then
                        NameLength = x - i
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                CommandGroup = True
                Continue For
            End If
            If NameLength > 0 Then
                Dim GroupName As String = regexToEval.Substring(i - 1, NameLength)
                i += NameLength : curChar = regexToEval.Substring(i - 1, 1) : AddStrToTrackers(GroupName & curChar)
                intGroups += 1
                DictGroups.Add(intGroups, "(" & DictGroups.Count & ")<" & GroupName & ">: " & vbTab)
                DictTrackers.Add(intGroups, True)
                Continue For
            End If
        End If
        curChar = iChar
        intGroups += 1
        DictGroups.Add(intGroups, "(" & DictGroups.Count & ")<" & intGroups.ToString & ">: " & vbTab)
        DictTrackers.Add(intGroups, True)
    Next
    Dim Output As String = MakeOutput()
End Sub

Private Function MakeOutput() As String
    Dim retString As String = String.Empty
    For i = 0 To DictGroups.Count - 1
        retString &= DictGroups(i) & vbCrLf
    Next
    Return retString
End Function

Public Sub EndGroup()
    If CommandGroup Then
        CommandGroup = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim HighestNum As Integer = 0
    For Each item In DictTrackers
        If Not item.Value Then Continue For
        If item.Key > HighestNum Then HighestNum = item.Key
    Next
    If HighestNum <> 0 Then DictTrackers(HighestNum) = False
End Sub

Public Sub AddStrToTrackers(ByVal addString As String)
    For Each item In DictTrackers
        If item.Value Then DictGroups(item.Key) &= addString
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

The only difference is that I'm not capturing either Non-Capture groups, nor function groups.  Of course, this is just quick code I made in like 10 minutes.  But it's a start if you want it.  I use the OrderedDictionary as Keys for Group-Numbers.  You could change that structure if you wanted to also include non-capture groups and function groups in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was basically looking for some in-built `.NET` libraries. Need some modification, but your code works fine in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a RegexParser class (internal) in the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace which you can call using Private Reflection. I have a [sample implementation](http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20003#58159) I've using in my FxCopContrib project so far.

There's the [RegexParser implementation from the Mono project](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System/System.Text.RegularExpressions) which you might be able to leverage.

Then there's [Deveel's Regex library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deveel-regex/files/).

Comment: From OP's question: `I am looking for a Non-RegEx solution`

Comment: These are Non-Regex solutions. The proposal is to use the parser used by the platform to parse the Regular Expressions and that gives you an object-graph of all the elements that make up the expression. Which seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for.